# Delete Screenshots In iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, screenshot, app-store-connect

I just submitted my app for reviewal and it is currently waiting. However, I submitted a screenshot that (accidentally) contained something that could possibly result in rejection if the reviewer is perceptive. It's very important that I delete it, but after spending the last hour on iTunes Connect I don't see an option for it.

Please help,
Thanks
--Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "x" in the upper corner of each image. Just click the little "edit" button on the details section, then the "x" for the image you want to delete.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly, awesome! I didn't think it wanted me to press the edit beforehand, and I never tried it. Thanks!

Comment: @JTApps - Glad I could help!! If I answered your question well I'd be super appreciative if you marked it as the answer :) Cheers!

Comment: Absolutely! There was a time limit before you can give it the check, but it's all yours! Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @Cfreak - Indeed, it looks like Apple has removed this option for existing apps - but it still functions identically for new versions / updates. I'd imagine this is to prevent developers from getting new screens in the app store which haven't gone through their review process.